# Printing strings and characters as hexadecimal in Go

Tags: string, go, char, hex, printf

Why cyrillic strings in hexadecimal format differ from cyrillic chars in hexadecimal format?

```
str  := "Э"
fmt.Printf("%x\n", str)
//result d0ad
    
str  := 'Э'
fmt.Printf("%x\n", str)
//result 42d
```

Comment: Bad framing. `str := 'Э'` is misleading as `'Э'` is _not_ a string, it not even is a "character". `'Э'` is basically an integer. Please study https://go.dev/blog/strings carefully.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with hexadecimal: The decimal, octal or binary representation would differ in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing the hexadecimal representation of a `string` prints the hex representation of its bytes, and printing the hexadecimal representation of a `rune` prints the hex representation of the number it is an alias to (`rune` is an alias to `int32`).

And `string`s in Go hold the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded byte sequence of the text. In UTF-8 representation characters (runes) having a numeric code > 127 have multi-byte representation.

The `rune` `Э` has multi-byte representation in UTF-8 (being `[208, 173]`), and it is not the same as the multi-byte representation of the 32-bit integer `1069 = 0x42d`. Integers are represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in memory.

Recommended blog post: [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings)